# PYTHON and mouse clicks and entering phrases into pop ups

Tags: python

I am trying to get python to emulatue mouse clicks, and then type a phrase into the pop up window that the mouse clicks into or the text box.

1) click a security box "run" link with mouse
2) move inside a pop up and enter different phrases with python

What would be the best way to control the mouse and keyboard in this function. These are based in windows. I just need to click " run " on pop up and then in another pop box in one text line enter a phrase then switch to another text line and enter another. much like a password User Id fields.

Could sommeone point me in the right direction.

Comment: You should specify your operating system and graphical environment for this question. Python is a multiplatform language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Python GUI library to interact with keyboard and mouse events. I prefer [wxPython](http://wxpython.org/) which is a very popular library. Take a look at wxPython key events API.

http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.KeyEvent-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Pywinauto](http://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/).

It should be straightforward to use, and you will be looking for functions such as TypeKeys and Click.

Comment: I get this   raceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python32/test", line 2, in <module>
    import pywinauto
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    import findwindows
ImportError: No module named findwindows

Comment: I see you are using Python 3.2. This may not yet be compatible with it yet. I have no problems using it with Python 2.6. Are you required to use Python 3.2?

Comment: yea I am. Kinda what I thought, any other ways around it?

Comment: All I can suggest is to downgrade. Why do you require Python 3? There is also win32com. http://python.net/crew/skippy/win32/Downloads.html But this also depends on 2.x Python. I'm not fully sure of what else there is available to Python 3.x

Comment: with the32com is it able to enter keyboard strokes, I am a little fimiliar with it